# Dynamic list - unknown type name Node

Tags: c, data-structures

I built a dynamic list on C which is supposed to save input words and write them on a txt file. I keep getting, however, this error:

```
lista.h:4:14: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 int is_empty(Node *head){
              ^~~~
              mode_t
lista.h:11:19: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void insert_first(Node **head_ref, Node *element){
                   ^~~~
                   mode_t
lista.h:11:36: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void insert_first(Node **head_ref, Node *element){
                                    ^~~~
                                    mode_t
lista.h:16:17: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void print_list(Node *head){
                 ^~~~
                 mode_t
lista.h:29:18: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void insert_last(Node **head, Node *element){
                  ^~~~
                  mode_t
lista.h:29:31: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void insert_last(Node **head, Node *element){
                               ^~~~
                               mode_t
lista.h:43:20: error: unknown type name ‘Node’; did you mean ‘mode_t’?
 void write_in_file(Node *head){
                    ^~~~
                    mode_t
```

which is strange, because i declared Node using typedef:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_empty(Node *head){
    if(head == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void insert_first(Node **head_ref, Node *element){
    element->next = *head_ref;
    *head_ref = element;
}

void print_list(Node *head){
    if(is_empty(head))
        printf("Lista vuota\n");
    else{
        Node *tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", tmp->parola);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}

void insert_last(Node **head, Node *element){
    Node *curr = *head, *prev = NULL;
    while(curr != NULL){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(prev == NULL)
        *head = element;
    else{
        prev->next = element;
        element = curr;
    }
}

void write_in_file(Node *head){
    Node *iterator = head;
    Node *tmp = head;
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+")) == NULL){
        printf("Impossibile creare il file\n");
    } else {
        while(iterator != NULL){
            fprintf(fptr, "%p    %s\n", &iterato->next, iterator->parola);
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
    }
}

struct list_node{
    struct list_node *next;
    char parola[500];
};

typedef struct list_node Node;

void print_usage();

int is_empty(Node *);

void print_list(Node *);

void insert_first( Node **, Node *);

void insert_last(Node **, Node *);

void write_in_file(Node *);
```

This is the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lista.h"

void print_usage(){
    printf("\n 1 per aggiungere una parola in fondo"
           "\n 2 per aggiungere in testa"
           "\n 3 per stampare tutto"
           "\n 4 per stampare quella con più vocali"
           "\n 5 per scrivere su file"
           "\n 6 per uscire\n");
}

int main(){

    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *item = NULL;
    int choice = 0;

    while(1){
        print_usage();
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){

            case 1:
                item = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                if(item == NULL) {
                    printf("Errore nella malloc");
                } else {
                    printf("Inserisci la parola da aggiungere\n");
                    scanf("%s", item->parola);

                    insert_last(&head, item);
                    puts("\n");
                }

                break;

            case 2:
                item = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                if(item == NULL) {
                    printf("Errore nella malloc");
                } else {
                    printf("Inserisci la parola da aggiungere");
                    scanf("%s", item->parola);

                    insert_first(&head, item);
                    puts("\n");
                }

                break;

            case 3:
                print_list(head);
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            case 5:
                write_in_file(head);
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("Exit\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
      }

}
```

I can't find the error, my idea is that it's in the function's declarations, it looks like Node is completely unknown to the compiler, although i declared it to point at the data structure using typedef

Comment: order matter just put the typedef in the top of your fonction !

Comment: Move the `struct list_node` definition and `typedef` at the top of the file.

Comment: Its not good practice to write the function definition in header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error `error: unknown type name ‘Node’` because the compiler does not find the definition of `Node` when compiling the content of `list.h` file.

That means, when compiler encounter this

```
int is_empty(Node *head){
```

till this point the `Node` is unknown to compiler because it is defined below in the code.

Note that, just moving the `typedef` before the use of `Node` will not solve your problem as it will be just the forward declaration of `struct list_node`. The compiler should know about the members of the structure as well before there usage in the code. So, you should move both the `struct list_node` definition and `typedef` `Node` before its usage in the file. Also, its not good practice to write the function definition in the header file. Just keep only the prototypes and structure definition in the header file and move the function definitions in a `.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not C# and you need to have the declarations & definitions **before** the first occurrence in the code.

```
Node node;

typedef int Node;
```

is WRONG but

```
typedef int Node;

Node node;
```

is correct

Comment: @H.S. Read what I wrote. **It is not C#**  But he thinks that it is. In C# order does not matter, in C matters. . It is common error made by people who have some experience in C# and they start to learn C

Comment: Thank you! I did not remember that